# sha1 encode exact value of parameter instead of the variable value

Tags: php

I'm working with an application that requires sha1 encoding for certain form values.

The problem is that when I use the following

```
<?php echo(hash("sha1","par1=".$_POST['p1']."&par2=".$_POST['p2'])); ?>
```

It gives me a sha1 encoding of the *actual* string, while I want to get a sha1 encoding of the posted values, so in this example I want to get

```
<?php echo(hash("sha1","par1=firstvalue&par2=secondvalue")); ?>
```

How can I realize this? Is it actually that simple and am I thinking way to difficult?

Comment: SHA1 is not an encoding scheme. It's a hash function. You do realize you won't be able to get the original string if you hash it, right?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Both lines gives me the same output.

Comment: Am I missing something? <?php `echo("par1=".hash("sha1",$_POST['p1'])."&par2=".hash("sha1",$_POST['p2'])); ?>`

Comment: Well, its for an online banking application that requires a sha1 output, but with the exact value of parameter instead of the variable value. I guess i don't understand the problem either, but they said i should use echo(hash("sha1","par1=firstvalue&par2=secondvalue")); otherwise i doesn't work..

Comment: @Dan, sounds like an solution expect i need the whole string in 1 hash, with the exact values of the 2 posted values

Comment: Sounds like this is some kind of signature check, to check against tampering - I guess it depends from bank to bank, for SagePay they use `MD5($value1.$value2.$value3 etc);`

Comment: So you do actually need the hash value of "firstvaluesecondvalue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because it identifies that para1=some_value as string not para1 as variable and some_value string
To achieve what you want you should hash every variable alone

Or I suggest that you implement your own encoding algorithm

Comment: I will recommend @Dan its good one 
<?php echo("par1=".hash("sha1",$_POST['p1'])."&par2=".hash("sha1",$_POST['p2'])); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this? Though I would have though either way would result in the same thing....

```
$hash_this = "par1=".$_POST['p1']."&par2=".$_POST['p2'];
echo sha1($hash_this);
```

Though that will do it if you want to hash the string of the values all together, rather than the values, if you want to store the values - then you should probably hash each value, so you could at least compare them later. Useful for a login system where you want to save a password to a database, which is more secure than literally just storing the password...

```
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
```

If you hash the string, you have no idea which value is wrong

Comment: Its the same as above but what he want is hashing every variable and assign it to para1 and 2